# tvOS: An issue while navigating

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, tvos

I am trying to navigate to another `UIViewController` and seems nothing works. My code is:

```
private func navigate() {

        let isAutoLogin = getAutologinValue()
        if isAutoLogin {

            let mainTabsController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Tabbar") as? LTTabbar
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainTabsController!, animated: true)

        }
        else {

            let subscribeController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SplashScreen") as? LTSplashCsreenController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(subscribeController!, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

I call navigate() in viewDidAppear. Should it work like this in tvOS? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method with a LTTabBar. 
What is wrong is to call this method with an instance of `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`... As you are doing in the second method.